# url.parse() returns undefined object keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i use url.parse(from the url module in node.js)it returns undefined object keys

i kept searching on internet and apparently most people use express.js so i didnt find any case similar to mine

here is the code(shortened):

```
var http = require('http');
var Url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
if (req.url != '/favicon.ico') {
    var q = Url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log(req.url);
    for (var key in q) {
        console.log(key + ':' + q.key);
    }
    console.log('closing');
    res.end();
}
}).listen(8080);
```

and the console displays this :

```
/?season=summer
protocol:undefined
slashes:undefined
auth:undefined
host:undefined
port:undefined
hostname:undefined
hash:undefined
search:undefined
query:undefined
pathname:undefined
path:undefined
href:undefined
parse:undefined
format:undefined
resolve:undefined
resolveObject:undefined
parseHost:undefined
closing
```

Comment: That is not the result of `Url.parse()`, but the result of `Url.parse().query`, what you store in `q`.

Comment: It should be equivalent to using ```p = Url.parse()```  then ```p.query``` but it still displays undefined for season

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `query` property of the parsed `Url` like you initially had it. You just need to access the value of the query object correctly.

Check the simplified example below (Note: `queryData[key]`):

```js
const url = require('url');

const queryData = url.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/status?season=summer', true).query;

for (const key in queryData) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${queryData[key]}`);
}
```

**Edit**:

The explanation for why you can't do something like `queryData.key` is that that would try to access a property in `queryData` object named 'key' and not the current `key` variable value (in this case 'season').

In this instance, the `queryData` object looks like this:

```js
var queryData = {
  'season': 'summer'
};
```

If you try to access `queryData.key` it is looking for the literal key called 'key' and not the value of the variable called `key` which happens to be season in the first iteration of the `for in` loop. Using `queryData[key]` allows you to access the value of the key assigned to the `key` variable.

Comment: can you explain to me why it doesnt work when i use queryData.key ? is the key an object as well?

Comment: FWIW the `query` object property of `Url.parse(req.url)` has a `null` prototype - so `queryData`  doesn't inherit `toString` from `Object.prototype`. This  is why `log ( queryData)`  throws an exception (can't convert to a primitive value) and individual properties need to be logged using the `for(...in)` loop,

Comment: @traktor53 Correct. Furthermore, to parse the query string, `Url.parse` uses the `querystring` module's `parse` method. You can get more details here: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: `var q = Url.parse(req.url, true).query;` you need to use `var q = Url.parse(req.url, true);`.

Otherwise q will already be Url.parse().query and the reset will not work/be undefined.

Comment: i updated the code to ```Url.parse()``` but the problem still persists